# Cursor position in textarea on click

Tags: javascript, function, cursor, textarea

I am working on a little emoji function. My problem is when I have a text in the textarea and select an emoji from the drop down it always goes to the end of the text even if I place the cursor at the beginning of the text, the emoji will go to the end of the text like so:

Some text here

The code:

```
function insertSmiley(smiley)
{
var currentText = document.getElementById("textarea");
var smileyWithPadding = " " + smiley + " ";
currentText.value += smileyWithPadding;
currentText.focus();
}
```

I tried to remove `currentText.focus();` but it didn't help. I also tried to use jQuery to keep the textarea's focus but the emoji would still go to the end of the text:

```
$(window).load(function(){    
var lastFocus;
$("#dropdown-emojis").mousedown(function(e) {
return false;
}); 
});
```

How can I make the emoji to show at the place where I place the cursor?

Answer (score 1):

use .selectionStart and .selectionEnd to know where the cursor is.

```
var startPosition = myElement.selectionStart;
    var endPosition = myElement.selectionEnd;
    if(startPosition == endPosition){ 
        newString= currentText.value.substring(0,startPosition)+ " " + smiley + " " + currentText.value.subString(endPosition,currentText.value.lenght());
```

Comment: For some reason I can't make it work. How would it look together with my code above?